# Heroku error "Couldn't find that app" when attempting to clone team repo

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm set up as a team member on another user's heroku project. I'm following the steps [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collab) to start contributing to their project.

In the team invite email I received, the name of the app is, e.g., 'name' (i.e. the text of the email was '...has invited you to join the "name" Team on Heroku as a member.'

But when I try to run "heroku git:clone -a name" as the instructions at the above collab article specify, I get the error "Couldn't find that app."

Am I using the wrong app name? How does Heroku know which team to look at? Or are app names unique to all Heroku users, and I can only clone ones on which I am a team member?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this one out as I was asking the question, so I'm posting the answer here.

"name" is the name of the team specified in the email from heroku, not the name of the app. Log into Heroku.com and select the specified team from the dropdown on the left. Click on "Apps" at the top and the app name is listed there. That's the name you should use in the clone command.